# Mongoose get Leagues which has upcoming matches

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've created a db structure as below. in this structure i would like to retrieve leagues which has matches from currentDate - 7 days and forward. My question is then whether this is possible with the current structure of my database or i need to change that before it is possible?

**League schema**

```
var leagueSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    league: Number

});
```

**Match schema**

```
var matchSchema   = new Schema({
    matchId: Number,
    leagueId: Number,
    date: Date,
    homeName: String,
    awayName: String,

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design could use some changes where you create references to documents in other collections for **[population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)** to be effective. Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s)
In your **`matchSchema`**, the `league` field is set to a number `_id`, where the ref option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during population, in this case the `League` model. The following example demonstrates the schema changes:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var leagueSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    league: Number
});

var matchSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    league: { type: Number, ref: 'League' },
    date: Date,
    homeName: String,
    awayName: String
});

var League  = mongoose.model('League', leagueSchema);
var Match = mongoose.model('Match', matchSchema);
```

When you are saving the documents, you simple assign the `_id` value on your refs, as in the following example:

```
var premierLeague = new League({ _id: 0, name: 'Premiership', league: 100 });

premierLeague.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    var matchDay = new Date(2015, 10, 7);
    var match = new Match({
        _id: 1,
        date: matchDay,
        league: premierLeague._id,    // assign the _id from the league
        homeName: "Manchester United",
        awayName: "West Brom"
    });

    match.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        // thats it!
    });
});
```

Now on to your query to retrieve leagues which has matches from currentDate - 7 days and forward, you populate your match's league using the query builder:

```
var oneWeekAgo = new Date();
oneWeekAgo.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7);

Match
    .find({ "date": { "$gte": oneWeekAgo } })
    .populate('league')
    .exec(function (err, matches) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log(matches);     
    });
```

Comment: This returns all matches with the league Id, however i want to retrieve all the leagues with upcoming games.